# Django source code won't update on server

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi

I have a Django website running and any updates I make to the source code won't update.

(Reason I'm changing the file is because one line of code is generating an error. What's weird is I commented out this line of code that causes the error, but the code still runs and thus still causes the error. In the `django.log` it shows that line causing the error still, but it also shows it commented out now. So the error log shows my new source code, but the application itself isn't executing the new code)

I am very new to Django, so I don't really know what's going on here (not my website, I got thrown on this project for work.)

Researching around for this, I have already tried to restart apache:

`$ sudo apachectl restart`

`$ sudo service apache2 restart`

and I've also tried to touch the `wsgi.py` file:

`$ touch wsgi.py`

and I have even deleted the `.pyc` file. Nothing has worked and the old line of code is still executing, even though the logs show it commented out.

Not sure where else to check or what else I'm missing.

Comment: Are you using mod_wsgi for apache to run Django, or are you running Django with uwsgi or gunicorn (behind apache)?  If the latter, make sure you are restarting that process as well.

Comment: What is it running on, is local or in production?

Comment: @JoeJ I have no clue. Where would I check that or how would I know?

Comment: @BigMonkey89WithaLeg it's online

Comment: @amallard if you do a "ps -ef" you might see "uwsgi" or "gunicorn" as one of the processes (separate from apache)

Comment: I think mod_wsgi. I have a `.load` and a `.conf` file in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`

Comment: `touch` will only work if using apache with mod_wsgi in daemon mode and not in old versions of mod_wsgi. It is important to understand which web server and wsgi you are using otherwise we cannot help you. Try working backwards: see which process listens to port 80, go through its configuration files etc.

Comment: Can you share the traceback ? One time I have run into this situation , but later I found strange behaviour of Django . The error were due to different line . Please share the django traceback , also tell me which Django version you are using .

Comment: @VidyaSagar I'll provide that in an answer. What's weird is that the one line of code was causing the error. I commented out that line, and another error occurred (as expected), then I uncommented the original line and the system worked again. It seems like just a fresh recompile of the file fixed the issue.

Comment: @VidyaSagar view my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Whichever service you are using, do a full stop and a full start (i.e., not just restart).

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo service apache2 start
```

If you are using uwsgi or gunicorn, you will have to do the same for them.  Some init scripts when issuing `restart` do not restart the master worker process which might cause a cached compiled version of your file to still reside in memory (with the incorrect code).

Comment: If you are using uwsgi the way to restart can vary

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @2ps I was able to figure out my problem. When I tried to stop Apache, the website was still up.

I realized there's another IP address for the website, so I'm guessing the first one must redirect to the second one?

Either way, I reopened SSH in the other IP address, restarted Apache and the source code updated immediately!

UPDATE:

As per @VidyaSagar request, I'm providing more info as it seems to be a weird fluke with Django. My OP was that a certain line of code was causing an error. I commented out this line, deleted the `.pyc` file, and restarted Apache. Another error occurred (as expected due to the code). So then I un-commented that line back to how it was previously, again deleted the `.pyc` and restarted Apache, and the system worked like normal. It seems that Django just wanted me to have a fresh re-compile of the file?

Django version: 1.7.4

Traceback of `django.log`

```
ERROR Internal Server Error: /upload/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/company/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/company/app/app/geo_app/views.py", line 306, in upload
    shutil.make_archive(kml_dir, 'zip', root_dir=kml_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 521, in make_archive
    save_cwd = os.getcwd()
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

ERROR Internal Server Error: /upload/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/company/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/company/app/app/geo_app/views.py", line 306, in upload
    # shutil.make_archive(kml_dir, 'zip', root_dir=kml_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 521, in make_archive
    save_cwd = os.getcwd()
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you with cPanel, if you go under "Setup Python App" and click "Restart" it should update. Saved me about 5 times.